# What are overtones and how do they relate to harmonics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, harmonics

> Problem 43. Two organ pipes, a pipe of fundamental frequency 440 Hz, closed at one end, and a pipe of fundamental frequency 660 Hz, open at both ends, produce overtones. Which choice below correctly describes overtones present in both pipes?
>
> a.    After the first overtone of each pipe, every second overtone of the first pipe matches every second overtone of the second pipe.
>
> b.    After the first overtone of each pipe, every second overtone of the first pipe matches every third overtone of the second pipe.
>
> c.    After the first overtone of each pipe, every third overtone of the first pipe matches every second overtone of the second pipe.
>
> d.    After the first overtone of each pipe, every second overtone of the first pipe matches every fourth overtone of the second pipe.
>
> e.    After the first overtone of each pipe, every third overtone of the first pipe matches every fourth overtone of the second pipe.

I was trying to solve this problem. However, the concept of [overtone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtone) is ambiguous. A search on the web gives me that an overtone is any frequency higher than the first harmonic. How can I use that to answer this question?

Comment: Hint: Pipes produce only sounds which are [standing waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave) within them. It's not hard to deduce the frequencies (or "overtones") each pipe will produce from this.

Comment: I did list out the frequencies:
for open-closed:
660, 1980, 3300, 4620...
for closed-closed:
440, 880, 1320, 1760...
I get no match...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in that the type of pipe for each of the two fundamental frequencies as described in your comment don't match the problem description.  The pipe with a fundamental frequency of 440Hz is open-closed, and the pipe with a fundamental frequency of 660Hz is open-open.  You actually said "closed-closed", which isn't even an option, but even if that's taken to mean "open-open", you've still got the fundamental frequencies backwards from what they are in the problem description.

Assuming you meant to say "open-open" instead of "closed-closed", you've got it right that open-open produces all integer multiples of the fundamental frequency, and open-closed produces only odd multiples; see the [Cylinders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_resonance#Cylinders) section of Wikipedia's [Acoustic resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_resonance) article.

The term "[overtone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtone)" does indeed mean any pitch higher than the fundamental frequency.  But you can assume for this problem that the only overtones involved are [harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic) overtones (overtones whose frequency is an integer multiple of the [fundamental frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_frequency)), and ignore the fact that musical instruments can also produce [inharmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inharmonicity) overtones.

Comment: Hi, this still does not work.

Comment: Look here:
for 440:
440, 1320, 2200, 3080, 3960, 4840...
for 660:
660, 1320, 1980, 2640, 3300....
The concordance is not constant. The "right" answer given by teacher is e. But that does not make sense. Sometimes 4 overtones later there is a match, other times only 2, other times only 3.

Comment: Never mind! It's all good.